# PGError: ERROR: relation "schema_migrations" does not exist when I heroku db:push

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, postgresql, heroku

I've a PostGresql database on my local system. I used it during development and I'm trying to test it out on the Heroku system.

Note I'm using PostGresql so that I can make use of the schemas.

I'm running the system perfectly on my local system.

I go to the Heroku page on how to push my DB to the server. http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/taps

```
> heroku db:push
```

After about 5 minutes I get

```
"PGError: ERROR:  relation "schema_migrations" does not exist"
```

What I'm wondering is two fold.. 
On a minor level I am wondering why this is happening. Is my database being reconstructed from scratch?
On a major level, I'm wondering how to I get around this.

**Brief: How do I get around the missing table on a db:push?**

---

To address concerns expressed in the answer given.

```
W:\RUBY\EDM>heroku run rake db:create
Running rake db:create attached to terminal... up, run.1
kzcgkswrss already exists

W:\RUBY\EDM>heroku run rake db:migrate
Running rake db:migrate attached to terminal... up, run.1

W:\RUBY\EDM>heroku db:push
Loaded Taps v0.3.23
Auto-detected local database: postgres://postgres:password@127.0.0.1/EDM2_develo
pment?encoding=utf8
Warning: Data in the app 'xxxx' will be overwritten and will not be r
ecoverable.

 !    WARNING: Potentially Destructive Action
 !     This command will affect the app: xxxx
 !    To proceed, type "xxxx" or re-run this command with --confirm c
xxxx

> xxxxx

Sending schema
Schema:        100% |==========================================| Time: 00:01:56
Sending indexes
schema_migrat: 100% |==========================================| Time: 00:00:01
....
users:         100% |==========================================| Time: 00:00:02
Sending data
31 tables, 5 records
schema_migrat:   0% |                                          | ETA:  --:--:--
Saving session to push_201202150351.dat..
!!! Caught Server Exception
HTTP CODE: 500
Taps Server Error: PGError: ERROR:  relation "schema_migrations" does not exist
```

---

### edit 2

It seems this error is related to a second schema that exists in postGresql.. 
It looks like it pushed all the empty tables in the public, but as soon as it tried to push up the second schema, it failed..

Comment: Really I'd love to understand how on an existing database, an upload of said DB would result in anything but a copy on the dest system.

Comment: I just edited my code.. It has been suggested that I run migrate first. Here I did just that.. Though the warning after the push indicates it was moot. So now.. onto the error.. How does one get through it?

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
 heroku rake db:push
```

Or perhaps if that doesn't work, do

```
 heroku rake db:migrate
```

first, and then try the second.

You're getting the missing table because you haven't created the table yet on Heroku. You need to create the DB and run the migrations. Yes, this will create a new DB.

UPDATE:

To quote Daniel Vandersluis (from [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1007187/exactly-what-does-rake-dbmigrate-do)):

> When you use rails migrations, a table called schema_migrations is automatically created, which keeps track of what migrations have been applied, by storing the version number of each migration (this is the number that prefaces the migration name in the file name, ie db/migrate/_20090617111204__migration.rb). When you run rake db:migrate to migrate up, only migrations which have not been run previously (ie. their version is not contained in the table) will be run (for this reason, changing a migration that's already been executed will have no effect when running db:migrate). When migrating down, all versions found in schema_migrations that are greater than the version you are rolling back to will be undone.

Comment: The "heroku db:push" is right off the heroku site.. so I hope it's right.

Comment: The table in question wouldn't be part of the migration.. I know i didn't create it.. It's the migration record, created by rails.

Comment: Finally.. as the table is in the db I'm trying to push, why would I have to do anything special?  Shouldn't doing a db:push copy the structure of the source DB, compleatly?

Comment: OH snot forgot.. as the tables in my database exist depending on the data in one table (my_schemas), and I have to run a schema creating rake.  How can I expect db:push to know what migration to run?

Comment: Also, you might want to keep the schema_migrations table. See http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Migration.html under "About the schema_migrations table"

Comment: Well I don't want my log on user table in each schema, nor do I want my "tenants" table in each.. They are only to be in the public "name space"..

Comment: We are getting off topic.. According to the rails doc you presented, the table is created by rails right?  They why the error? How could it not exist?  And more to the point, how do I get around it?

Comment: I don't understand the stigma against the schema_migrations table -- all it does is keep track of which migrations to run. Furthermore, if you want to use rake migrations, I'm fairly sure you need this table (see updated answer).

Comment: Furthermore, as I said before, you need to create a DB on heroku just like you need to create a db on your local machine. You do this locally when you do "rake db:migrate", so why should it be any different on Heroku?

Comment: don't have a problem with the table mate.. I'm not trying to create a database on heroku.. I'm trying to push up my existing database. db:push.. when I do this, it drops the current db and pushes the one on my system.. I did of course try the heroku db:create and heroku:db migrate.. But... And this bit is important.. Running my individual schema based rake on an empty database would result in it doing nothing.. That is data reliant.. No data, no migration..

Comment: Why would db:push require a migration?  How does it know to run custom rake files?  How does it know when to run them?  Schemas require custom rakes?  should I run those before or after the I attempt to upload the database..

Comment: Okay, if you've already made a DB I'm pretty sure you can do rake db:push --table TABLENAME. Although I'm unsure how you could create a DB without doing a rake db:create..

Answer (score 0):

did you run your migrations on heroku itself?

```
$ heroku run rake db:migrate
```

If you didn't then probably that's it